# Add style to a JavaScript Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add some style to a JavaScript Widget but I have tried it with CSS and does not work.

Here is my .js

```
YUI().use('tabview', function (Y) {
            var tabview = new Y.TabView({
                children: [{
                    label: '<div>Tecnología y negocios</div>',
                    content:'<section class="texto">En los últimos<img class="imapple" alt="" src="images/apple.png" height="400" width="400"/></section>'
                },
                {
                    label: '<div>La telefonía móvil</div>',
                    content:'<div class="texto">Repasamos<img alt="" src="images/exposiciones.jpg" height="700" width="700"/></div>'
                },
                {
                    label: '<div>Alan Turing</div>',
                    content:'<div class="texto">En la entrada<img alt="" src="images/alanturing.jpg" height="700" width="500"/></div>'
                },
                {
                    label: '<div>Evolución tecnológica</div>',
                    content:'<div class="texto">En la zona.<img alt="" src="images/evolution.jpg" height="700" width="700" /></div>'
                }]
            }).render('#miTabview');
            if ( !tab.get('active') ) {
                tab.set('contentVisible', false, true); /* hide if not active */
            } else {
                this.set('activeTab', tab, true);

            }
        });
```

The script is shown top of the page in the left. I want it to be in the middle.
Here is my HTML

```
<div class="expo" id="exposiciones">
        <script  src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.14.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
        <script  class="expo" src="js/Exposiciones.js"></script>
 </div>
```

And here the CSS

```
.expo{
position: absolute;left: 50px;top: 25px;}
```

Comment: Can you provide a functional fiddle?

Comment: You have to style the content (#miTabview), not the script section of your DOM

Comment: @iScor could you give me an example of how to do it?